# .NET MAUI Switch Color Change is not Persistent

Tags: .net, xaml, user-interface, maui

I want to implement a switch in a .NET MAUI application. However, I further want to adjust the colour.
Unfortunately, the changes appear at first:

[image]

Now, turn the switch off:

[image]

And again, turn the switch on:

[image]

Why is the colour adjustment not persistent?

**XAML code**:

```xml
<Switch Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        IsToggled="True"
        OnColor="{StaticResource SnowWhite}"
        ThumbColor="{StaticResource AlpineBlue}" />
```

I've tried not that much because I can't think of a potential source.

Comment: Does this also happen when you change the default colors in the *Styles.xaml* resource dictionary?

Comment: Where are `SnowWhite` and `AlpineBlue` defined?

Comment: @LukeVo SnowWhite and AlpineBlue are defined in App.xaml in the Application.Resources.

Comment: Yes, it is just the case as you said. And there is a known issue about this, you can follow it up here: [Switch control ignores OnColor and ThumbColor](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19380).